# How to use cucumber with bazel?

Tags: cucumber, bazel, cucumber-cpp

I am trying to create a [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) project which includes [cucumber-cpp](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp). I could not figure out how its `BUILD` file would look like.

As [Google Test](https://github.com/google/googletest) now includes it's own `BUILD` file it is as easy as it get's. Something similar would be nice.

My `WORKSPACE` file looks like this

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "googletest",
    sha256 = "927827c183d01734cc5cfef85e0ff3f5a92ffe6188e0d18e909c5efebf28a0c7",
    strip_prefix = "googletest-release-1.8.1",
    url = "https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/release-1.8.1.zip",
)

http_archive(
    name = "cucumber-cpp",
    sha256 = "73fddda099e39cc51ebee99051047067f6dcd437fbde60601ac48cb82a903dac",
    url = "https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-cpp/archive/v0.5.zip",
)
```

My specification `BUILD` file

```
cc_test(
    name = "app-spec",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        "//src:app-lib",
        "@cucumber-cpp//:main", //do not know if this is correct
    ],
)

cc_test(
    name = "app-spec",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        "//src:app-lib",
        "@cucumber-cpp//:main", //do not know if this is correct
    ],
)
```

Test `BUILD` file

```
cc_test(
    name = "app-test",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.cpp"]),
    deps = [
        "//src:app-lib",
        "@googletest//:gtest_main",
    ],
)
```

But obviously the `cucumber-cpp` is not built so I wonder how it's Bazel BUILD file would look like?

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to do this, but couldn't find anything where anyone had attempted it. In the end I wrote a dedicated bazel extension for using cucumber and gherkin feature specs. Currently this only supports `(linux|osx)+cpp+cucumber`, but I may add support for windows and other languages further down the line. To use this add this to your WORKSPACE file;

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")
git_repository(
    name = "rules_gherkin",
    commit = "ef361f40f9716ad8a3c6a8a21111bb80d4cbd927", # Update this to match latest commit
    remote = "https://github.com/silvergasp/rules_gherkin.git"
)
load("@rules_gherkin//:gherkin_deps.bzl","gherkin_deps")
gherkin_deps()

load("@rules_gherkin//:gherkin_workspace.bzl","gherkin_workspace")
gherkin_workspace()
```

An example BUILD file would look like this;

```py
load("//gherkin:defs.bzl", "gherkin_library", "gherkin_test")

gherkin_library(
    name = "feature_specs",
    srcs = glob(["**/*.feature"]),
)

gherkin_test(
    name = "calc_test",
    steps = ":calculator_steps",
    deps = [":feature_specs"],
)

load("//gherkin:defs.bzl", "cc_gherkin_steps")

cc_gherkin_steps(
    name = "calculator_steps",
    srcs = [
        "CalculatorSteps.cpp",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = [
        "//examples/Calc/src:calculator",
        "@cucumber_cpp//src:cucumber_main",
        "@gtest",
    ],
)
```

A complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/silvergasp/rules_gherkin/tree/main/examples/Calc/features).